# Missing connection between /map and /base_link

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi at all,

I am very new to ROS. After working out the tutorials and the Book "ROS by example"
I got the following error, when running rviz with my personal robot.model:

> > > 

Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between '/map' and '/base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.  <<<

In my urdf File I have got only base and a link to a Laser_link, which is not used yet.

I looked through many files comparing mine with the turtlebot-files. I dont understand where the link  between base_link and map is made, I believe it is in the move_base but I really dont know. If it helps I can send the content of files but dont know which one.

Hope that someone here can help me.

Thanks and best wishes

Michael,
Berlin, Germany

#### EDIT

Sorry for asking again. I get the error in the console when running roslaunch myrobot fake_turtlebot.launch, not in rviz, si the error message doesnt depend on my settings in rviz. I do this too find out and compare my file with turtlebot-tutorial, why my robot isnt operating correct, eg. when I want to run move_base and click in the map to define a goal. When I run myrobot myrobot.lauch the rviz shows the thin blue line as path to the goal correctly, but is moving somewhere in the wrong direction with flashing the red lines.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61759/missing-connection-between-/map-and-/base_link/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In RViz in the global options you can choose fixed frame. Is it map? Try choosing "base_link" as your fixed frame.
You can have a look at the image below and that is my robot model in rviz.

[link text](https://portal.bitcasa.com/send/bbb86466824c8ef50a8b4c01f34bd3fde55d50a9c1bf27c9588f4350e7039ee9/39b88c7ecd95c50b44c0d3fc722d96a1dba01e2989a07e4c32586c9fdfd1986a)

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-04-29**:
Thank you very much, for your rapid help and the provided image. Yes, it is set to /map. I will try changing this tomorrow when I am back to my work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#coordinate-frames to understand the various frames used.

Use `rosrun tf tf_monitor` or `rosrun tf view_frames` to see if the required frames are being broadcast.

In general, the /map (to /odom or /base_link) frame is broadcast by a localization node (eg. amcl or gmapping). The /odom (to /base_link) frame is broadcast by an odometry producing node (eg. from your wheel encoders or robot_pose_ekf).

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3